# C# Get cookies from a request that uses a proxy

Tags: c#, cookies, proxy

I am trying to make a program that logs into an website named ROBLOX. And then check the stats of the account with a API that ROBLOX has made their self.

So this is my login code:

```
public static void MainLogin(string user, string pass, string ip, int port)
{

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.roblox.com/NewLogin");
    string postData = String.Format("username={0}&password={1}&submitLogin=Log+In&ReturnUrl=", user, pass);
    byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
    WebProxy myproxy = new WebProxy(ip, port);
    myproxy.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;
    request.Proxy = myproxy;
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.ContentLength = data.Length;

    using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }
    reqCookie = RetrieveCookie(request);



}
```

With that it logs in, ad you can see at the last line of it, it says 'RetrieveCookie'. That is another function I made to get the cookie I want. The cookie I want is called: '.ROBLOSECURITY=_'. This is my retrievecookie function:

```
private static string RetrieveCookie(HttpWebRequest htr)
{
    using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)htr.GetResponse())
    {

        foreach (string item in response.Headers.Keys)
        {

            if (item == "Set-Cookie")
            {

                int Start = response.Headers[item].IndexOf(".ROBLOSECURITY=_", 0);
                int End = response.Headers[item].IndexOf("; domain=", Start);
                return response.Headers[item].Substring(Start, End - Start);

            }


        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

As you can see, the request is getting sended back here. And I am getting an error at:

```
int End = response.Headers[item].IndexOf("; domain=", Start);
```

The error that I get from this is:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
```

I dont really know what it means, but it has to do something with the proxy. Because when I **dont** use the proxy, it just works fine!

> How can I let this work with proxy, and is this even possible?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Its likely got nothing to do with a proxy but how you parse the value (`Start` is `-1` for any other cookie).  You need to filter with `if (Start >= 0) { ... handle your cookie and break .. }` - If you get no result then the value is not what you think it is.

Comment: @AlexK. OMG tnx. I writed `.ROBLOSECURITY=_` after a little bit of research, I found out it has to be `.ROBLOSECURITY` Thanks for waking me up! haha. You let me look at that again!